# Can't get an initial context of WebLogic server on Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, jms, weblogic, playframework-2.2

I have an application running on Play Framework 2, and I also have a WebLogic server 10.3.6 running on the same machine. (The Play application isn't deployed on the WebLogic server.)
In the Play application, I'm trying to send a JMS to the WebLogic server.

I use a class that works perfectly well in a standalone Java application--specifically, WebLogic's example of how to send JMS messages. However, when I try to run the same class in the Play application, it fails to get an initial context. No error is thrown, the application simply hangs and does nothing when it comes to getting the initial context.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, put a try/catch block around your code that's looking up the initial context and log any errors.  It may be that there's an issue with logging, or it could also be that the lookup is happening statically when the class is loaded - in that situation error reporting becomes really hard to impossible.

Comment: No, that's not it. The code is surrounded with try-catch that should print to stdout upon catching any Exception whatsoever, but it never happens. The lookup doesn't happen on the loading of the class either. My guess is it can't reach the server but there's no timeout set, but I can't understand why it wouldn't be able to reach it.